# Vuex selector like redux reselect

Tags: redux, vuex, nuxt.js

In my nuxt project, I have props that can be deduced from other store attributes.

In redux, I would use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to compute those every time it is necessary, when the store is mutated, and not necessarily at every render?

How can I achieve the same with nuxt/vuex?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're after are [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html).

> Vuex allows us to define "getters" in the store. You can think of them as computed properties for stores. Like computed properties, a getter's result is cached based on its dependencies, and will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed.

```
// store/index.js

export const state = () => ({
  todos: [
    { id: 1, text: '...', done: true },
    { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
  ]
})

export const getters =  {
  doneTodos: state => {
    return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.done)
  }
}
```

```
mounted() {
  // accessing in a component
  this.$store.getters.doneTodos
}
```

Check out the documentation I linked, which has more examples, including how use method based getters, which don't cache the result.

If your getter is defined within a module then the the syntax is a little different.  You need to do `store.getters['module/doneTodos']`, where `module` is the name of the store module you have.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for!